# Joining tables in rails based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails and I have a question on joining two tables in rails

I have two tables:-

TableA(Id, ancestry_depth,...) where the depth has been created using ancestry gem
TableB(Id,TableA_id, TableC_id)

I want to extract the column TableA_id with some conditions and My sql statement will look like this

```
(select * from TableB
join TableA
on TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_id
where ancestry_depth = 5)
```

I am not able to convert this query into rails query

Please help me with the best way to do this in rails4.1.2

Comment: have you read the Rails docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this:

```
# TableB.joins(<association name>).where(<table name>: { ancestry_depth: "5" })
TableB.joins(:tablea).where(tableas: { ancestry_depth: "5" })
```

Since you are in Rails 4, you might also be interested in checking out the `merge` option which would allow you to define the TableA conditions in a scope in that model, keeping them separate from the TableB logic.  Something like...

```
# In TableA class:
scope :my_ancestry_scope, -> { where(ancestry_depth: "5") }

# The join query:
TableB.joins(:tablea).merge(TableA.my_ancestry_scope)
```